# Converting a string to a date format?

Tags: python, date, format

I would like to convert a string '17.07.2019' to date format 17-07-2019 (or 17-Jul-2019)

I tried this code

```
from datetime import datetime
x = '17.07.2019'    
y=datetime.strptime(x,'%d.%m.%y')    
y=datetime.strftime(x,'%d.%m.%y')
```

but I get this error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'
```

I then tried

```
y=pd.to_datetime(x,'%d.'%m.%Y')
```

but I got this error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strftime` is used to convert `datetime` to `str`, `strptime` is used to convert `str` to `datetime`.

This is what you need:

```
from datatime import datetime as date
x = '17.07.2019'
y = date.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y')
new_format = y.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

you also can convert to the new format directly

```
new_format = date.strptime('17.07.2019', '%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `str.replace` for something this simple.

```
y = x.replace('.', '-')
```

Or to fix your code you need to just use `strftime` on `y`:

```
y = date.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y')
z = y.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```